# How to get XML uncommented section using sed/awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an XML file in my linux box & I want to read the lines which are not commented.
Example :

Input File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This is an example
     don't read it while working -->
<ccb>
                <ccc>
                        <aaa>true</aaa>
                        <bbb>name_1</bbb>
                        <Port>1534</Port>
            <datPort>1532</datPort>
<!--
                        <e214>
                                <ImsiPrefixLen>5</ImsiPrefixLen>
                                <LocalPrefix>97252</LocalPrefix>
                        </e214>
-->

                </ccc>
</ccb>
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ccb>
                <ccc>
                        <aaa>true</aaa>
                        <bbb>name_1</bbb>
                        <Port>1534</Port>
            <datPort>1532</datPort>
                </ccc>
</ccb>
```

Comment: Don't use `sed` or `awk`; use a real XML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in XML a comment starts with `<!--` and ends with `-->`; It can't contain `--`.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef$/}s/<!--.*?-->//gs' <<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This is an example
 don't read it while working -->
<ccb>
            <ccc>
                    <aaa>true</aaa>
                    <bbb>name_1</bbb>
                    <Port>1534</Port>
        <datPort>1532</datPort>
<!--
                    <e214>
                            <ImsiPrefixLen>5</ImsiPrefixLen>
                            <LocalPrefix>97252</LocalPrefix>
                    </e214>
-->

            </ccc>
</ccb>
END
```

Explanation

```
perl -h

-p : assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed

BEGIN block executed once at beginning to unset the input record separator ($/) because of multiline matching <!--  -->

s/// : substitute function (/ can be replaced by any other character)

<!--.*?--> : .* any string ? lazy modifier to get the shortest match

s : modifier so that . matches also newline character
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can you explain me the command "perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef$/}s/<!--.*?-->//gs'"